# Getting Run time error 424 while trying to run stored procedure from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I am trying to execute/commit stored procedure (call queries) from Excel but getting run time error '424'. I have always tried fetching data using select query by making connection between Excel and Oracle through vba but handling stored procedure for the first time.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

```
Public DBConn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub createconn()

Dim UserId, Password As String
Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
Server = "XXXXX"
UserId = "XXXXX"
Password = "XXXXXX"
With DBConn
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;" & _
    "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
    "SERVER=" & Server & ";" & _
    "UID=" & UserId & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
End With

End Sub

Sub Final()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim DBresults As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlquery As String, wsData As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Set DBresults = New ADODB.Recordset

Set wsData = Worksheets("JPM trades")

lRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
If lRow > 1 Then

Call createconn
  lRow = 2
  Do Until Cells(lRow, 8) = ""
   If Cells(lRow, 8) <> "--" Then Conn.Execute Cells(lRow, 8)
   lRow = lRow + 1
   Loop
    
End If

Call close_conn
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
    

Sub close_conn()

DBConn.Close
End Sub
```

This is how I am creating the connection:

```
Public Sub createconn()

Dim UserId, Password As String
Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
Server = "XXXXX"
UserId = "XXXXX"
Password = "XXXXXX"
With DBConn
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;" & _
    "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
    "SERVER=" & Server & ";" & _
    "UID=" & UserId & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: code breaks at this line      Then Conn.Execute Cells(lRow, 8)

Comment: Variable `Conn` is not defined, always use `Option Explicit` in every module.

Comment: Please, show us how `createconn` looks. Where `Conn` variable has been declared? Or, if you show us `createconn` we may make suggestions to transform it in a Function returning 'Conn`

Comment: You are defining `DBConn`, but using `Conn` with is undefined. See @BrakNicku comment

Comment: let me try using DBConn

Comment: Does `Cells(lRow, 8)` come from `wsData` also?

Comment: yes, 8 represents column H

Comment: after changing conn to DBconn.Exceute getting a new error = ODBC Driveer for oracle sql command not ended properly

Comment: @Naina i think you should also prefix the `cells` with the sheet you are referring to.

Comment: `DBConn` is declared as a local variable in another Sub and it is lost when that Sub ends. Try transforming the sub in a function in this way: Replace `Public Sub createconn()` with `Public Function createconn() As ADODB.Connection` and end it with `Set createconn = DBConn`. Then call it in the next way: `Dim conn as ADODB.Connection`. followed by `Set conn = createconn`. Then, fully qualify the range to return the string.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru changing Conn to DBconn and removing semi colon from the end of the store proc made it work

Answer (score 1):

To connect to oracle db I prefer to use DSN defined in ODBC. You can press windows key and type ODBC. Use ODBC DATA SOURCE (32bit) (Windows does not provide drivers for 64 bit Excel). I prefer to use Oracle ODBC drivers.

My code to connect to database:

```
Set Con = New ADODB.Connection
Con.ConnectionString = "DSN=here_DSN_name;UID=username;PWD=here_passowrd;"
Con.Open
```

To execute Oracle procedure I'm using code:

```
Set CMD = New ADODB.Command
    CMD.CommandType = adCmdText
    Set CMD.ActiveConnection = Con
```

Then you need to now what arguments your procedure uses and create parameters.

```
    Set a_ = CMD.CreateParameter("a_", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 32000, param1)
    CMD.Parameters.Append a_
    Set b_ = CMD.CreateParameter("b_", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 32000, param2)
    CMD.Parameters.Append b_
    Set c_ = CMD.CreateParameter("c_", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 32000, param3)
    CMD.Parameters.Append c_
    Set d_ = CMD.CreateParameter("d_", adVarChar, adParamInputOutput, 32000, param4)
    CMD.Parameters.Append d_
    Set e_ = CMD.CreateParameter("e_", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, param5)
    CMD.Parameters.Append e_
    
    CMD.CommandText = "{CALL your_procedure_here(? , ? , ? , ?, ? )}"
    CMD.CommandTimeout = Cmd_timOut
```

Be careful with `adVarchar`, which is what data type the parameter is and `adParamInputOutput` or `adParamInput` or `adParamOutput`, which defines if you only send parameter to procedure or can receive something back.
Then you execute procedure:

```
CMD.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
```

I'm always calling procedures which do not return a recordset and that's why I'm using `adExecuteNoRecords`. You can read from parameters using

```
your_variable = b_
```

to read from parameter `b_`